# Composer update doesn’t install PHPUnit in Laravel?

Tags: php, json, laravel-4, phpunit, composer-php

I am trying to install [PHPUnit](http://phpunit.de) into the [Laravel](http://laravel.com) framework via [Composer](https://getcomposer.org).

The problem is that the required files are not downloaded after running composer update.

My process looks like this:

First, I insert PHPUnit requirement in `composer.json`. The whole file looks like this:

```
{
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
    "keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
    "license": "MIT",
    "require": {
        "laravel/framework": "4.1.*",
        "laravelbook/ardent": "dev-master",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "4.2.*" // i have also tried with 3.7 and 3.8
    },
    "autoload": {
        "classmap": [
            "app/commands",
            "app/controllers",
            "app/models",
            "app/database/migrations",
            "app/database/seeds",
            "app/tests/TestCase.php",
            "app/filters"
        ]
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "php artisan clear-compiled",
            "php artisan optimize"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "php artisan clear-compiled",
            "php artisan optimize"
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "php artisan key:generate"
        ]
    },
    "config": {
        "preferred-install": "dist"
    },
    "minimum-stability": "stable",
        "require": {
            "laravelbook/ardent": "dev-master"
        }

}
```

Next, I run `composer update -vvv`. The dump looks like this (Bonus Weirdness: This is copied from command prompt, wierdly enough if i do the same command but try to write it to a txt file with the > command, the process hangs after the `Downloading https://packagist.org/packages.json` line)

```
C:\wamp\www\Dropbox\ltest>composer update -vvv
Reading ./composer.json
Executing command (CWD): git describe --exact-match --tags
Executing command (CWD): git branch --no-color --no-abbrev -v
Loading composer repositories with package information
Downloading https://packagist.org/packages.json
Writing C:/Users/aske/AppData/Local/Composer/repo/https---packagist.org/packages
.json into cache
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Reading C:/Users/aske/AppData/Local/Composer/repo/https---packagist.org/p-provid
er-active.json from cache
Reading C:/Users/aske/AppData/Local/Composer/repo/https---packagist.org/p-provid
er-archived.json from cache
Reading C:/Users/aske/AppData/Local/Composer/repo/https---packagist.org/p-provid
er-latest.json from cache
Reading C:/Users/aske/AppData/Local/Composer/repo/https---packagist.org/p-provid
er-stale.json from cache
Reading C:/Users/aske/AppData/Local/Composer/repo/https---packagist.org/provider
-laravelbook$ardent.json from cache
Reading C:/Users/aske/AppData/Local/Composer/repo/https---packagist.org/provider
-laravel$laravel.json from cache
Reading C:/Users/aske/AppData/Local/Composer/repo/https---packagist.org/provider
-psr$log.json from cache
Reading C:/Users/aske/AppData/Local/Composer/repo/https---packagist.org/provider
-symfony$http-foundation.json from cache
Reading C:/Users/aske/AppData/Local/Composer/repo/https---packagist.org/provider
-symfony$http-kernel.json from cache
Reading C:/Users/aske/AppData/Local/Composer/repo/https---packagist.org/provider
-stack$builder.json from cache
Reading C:/Users/aske/AppData/Local/Composer/repo/https---packagist.org/provider
-symfony$event-dispatcher.json from cache
Reading C:/Users/aske/AppData/Local/Composer/repo/https---packagist.org/provider
-symfony$debug.json from cache
Reading C:/Users/aske/AppData/Local/Composer/repo/https---packagist.org/provider
-predis$predis.json from cache
Reading C:/Users/aske/AppData/Local/Composer/repo/https---packagist.org/provider
-phpseclib$phpseclib.json from cache
Reading C:/Users/aske/AppData/Local/Composer/repo/https---packagist.org/provider
-nesbot$carbon.json from cache
Reading C:/Users/aske/AppData/Local/Composer/repo/https---packagist.org/provider
-monolog$monolog.json from cache
Reading C:/Users/aske/AppData/Local/Composer/repo/https---packagist.org/provider
-nikic$php-parser.json from cache
Reading C:/Users/aske/AppData/Local/Composer/repo/https---packagist.org/provider
-jeremeamia$superclosure.json from cache
Reading C:/Users/aske/AppData/Local/Composer/repo/https---packagist.org/provider
-jeremeamia$functionparser.json from cache
Reading C:/Users/aske/AppData/Local/Composer/repo/https---packagist.org/provider
-ircmaxell$password-compat.json from cache
Reading C:/Users/aske/AppData/Local/Composer/repo/https---packagist.org/provider
-filp$whoops.json from cache
Reading C:/Users/aske/AppData/Local/Composer/repo/https---packagist.org/provider
-d11wtq$boris.json from cache
Reading C:/Users/aske/AppData/Local/Composer/repo/https---packagist.org/provider
-symfony$console.json from cache
Reading C:/Users/aske/AppData/Local/Composer/repo/https---packagist.org/provider
-symfony$filesystem.json from cache
Reading C:/Users/aske/AppData/Local/Composer/repo/https---packagist.org/provider
-symfony$finder.json from cache
Reading C:/Users/aske/AppData/Local/Composer/repo/https---packagist.org/provider
-classpreloader$classpreloader.json from cache
Reading C:/Users/aske/AppData/Local/Composer/repo/https---packagist.org/provider
-patchwork$utf8.json from cache
Reading C:/Users/aske/AppData/Local/Composer/repo/https---packagist.org/provider
-swiftmailer$swiftmailer.json from cache
Reading C:/Users/aske/AppData/Local/Composer/repo/https---packagist.org/provider
-symfony$browser-kit.json from cache
Reading C:/Users/aske/AppData/Local/Composer/repo/https---packagist.org/provider
-symfony$css-selector.json from cache
Reading C:/Users/aske/AppData/Local/Composer/repo/https---packagist.org/provider
-symfony$dom-crawler.json from cache
Reading C:/Users/aske/AppData/Local/Composer/repo/https---packagist.org/provider
-symfony$process.json from cache
Reading C:/Users/aske/AppData/Local/Composer/repo/https---packagist.org/provider
-symfony$routing.json from cache
Reading C:/Users/aske/AppData/Local/Composer/repo/https---packagist.org/provider
-symfony$security.json from cache
Reading C:/Users/aske/AppData/Local/Composer/repo/https---packagist.org/provider
-symfony$translation.json from cache
Reading C:/Users/aske/AppData/Local/Composer/repo/https---packagist.org/provider
-laravel$framework.json from cache
Reading C:/Users/aske/AppData/Local/Composer/repo/https---packagist.org/provider
-doctrine$dbal.json from cache
Reading C:/Users/aske/AppData/Local/Composer/repo/https---packagist.org/provider
-doctrine$common.json from cache
Reading C:/Users/aske/AppData/Local/Composer/repo/https---packagist.org/provider
-doctrine$inflector.json from cache
Reading C:/Users/aske/AppData/Local/Composer/repo/https---packagist.org/provider
-doctrine$cache.json from cache
Reading C:/Users/aske/AppData/Local/Composer/repo/https---packagist.org/provider
-doctrine$collections.json from cache
Reading C:/Users/aske/AppData/Local/Composer/repo/https---packagist.org/provider
-doctrine$lexer.json from cache
Reading C:/Users/aske/AppData/Local/Composer/repo/https---packagist.org/provider
-doctrine$annotations.json from cache
Reading C:/Users/aske/AppData/Local/Composer/repo/https---packagist.org/provider
-illuminate$support.json from cache
Reading C:/Users/aske/AppData/Local/Composer/repo/https---packagist.org/provider
-illuminate$database.json from cache
Reading C:/Users/aske/AppData/Local/Composer/repo/https---packagist.org/provider
-illuminate$validation.json from cache
Reading C:/Users/aske/AppData/Local/Composer/repo/https---packagist.org/provider
-illuminate$container.json from cache
Reading C:/Users/aske/AppData/Local/Composer/repo/https---packagist.org/provider
-illuminate$events.json from cache
Reading C:/Users/aske/AppData/Local/Composer/repo/https---packagist.org/provider
-illuminate$auth.json from cache
Reading C:/Users/aske/AppData/Local/Composer/repo/https---packagist.org/provider
-illuminate$cache.json from cache
Reading C:/Users/aske/AppData/Local/Composer/repo/https---packagist.org/provider
-illuminate$config.json from cache
Reading C:/Users/aske/AppData/Local/Composer/repo/https---packagist.org/provider
-illuminate$console.json from cache
Reading C:/Users/aske/AppData/Local/Composer/repo/https---packagist.org/provider
-illuminate$cookie.json from cache
Reading C:/Users/aske/AppData/Local/Composer/repo/https---packagist.org/provider
-illuminate$encryption.json from cache
Reading C:/Users/aske/AppData/Local/Composer/repo/https---packagist.org/provider
-illuminate$exception.json from cache
Reading C:/Users/aske/AppData/Local/Composer/repo/https---packagist.org/provider
-illuminate$filesystem.json from cache
Reading C:/Users/aske/AppData/Local/Composer/repo/https---packagist.org/provider
-illuminate$foundation.json from cache
Reading C:/Users/aske/AppData/Local/Composer/repo/https---packagist.org/provider
-illuminate$hashing.json from cache
Reading C:/Users/aske/AppData/Local/Composer/repo/https---packagist.org/provider
-illuminate$html.json from cache
Reading C:/Users/aske/AppData/Local/Composer/repo/https---packagist.org/provider
-illuminate$http.json from cache
Reading C:/Users/aske/AppData/Local/Composer/repo/https---packagist.org/provider
-illuminate$log.json from cache
Reading C:/Users/aske/AppData/Local/Composer/repo/https---packagist.org/provider
-illuminate$mail.json from cache
Reading C:/Users/aske/AppData/Local/Composer/repo/https---packagist.org/provider
-illuminate$pagination.json from cache
Reading C:/Users/aske/AppData/Local/Composer/repo/https---packagist.org/provider
-illuminate$queue.json from cache
Reading C:/Users/aske/AppData/Local/Composer/repo/https---packagist.org/provider
-illuminate$redis.json from cache
Reading C:/Users/aske/AppData/Local/Composer/repo/https---packagist.org/provider
-illuminate$routing.json from cache
Reading C:/Users/aske/AppData/Local/Composer/repo/https---packagist.org/provider
-illuminate$session.json from cache
Reading C:/Users/aske/AppData/Local/Composer/repo/https---packagist.org/provider
-illuminate$translation.json from cache
Reading C:/Users/aske/AppData/Local/Composer/repo/https---packagist.org/provider
-illuminate$view.json from cache
Reading C:/Users/aske/AppData/Local/Composer/repo/https---packagist.org/provider
-illuminate$workbench.json from cache
Reading C:/Users/aske/AppData/Local/Composer/repo/https---packagist.org/provider
-symfony$security-acl.json from cache
Reading C:/Users/aske/AppData/Local/Composer/repo/https---packagist.org/provider
-symfony$security-core.json from cache
Reading C:/Users/aske/AppData/Local/Composer/repo/https---packagist.org/provider
-symfony$security-csrf.json from cache
Reading C:/Users/aske/AppData/Local/Composer/repo/https---packagist.org/provider
-symfony$security-http.json from cache
Nothing to install or update
Reading ./composer.lock
Generating autoload files
Executing command (CWD): php artisan clear-compiled
Executing command (CWD): php artisan optimize
Generating optimized class loader
```

And in the end required files are not added to `vendor/bin/`. As far as I know a file called `phpunit.php` should have been placed there at this point, but there is no sign of it.

[Here is my `composer.lock`](http://pastebin.com/bkWuFRZR) as bonus info, no sign of any phpunit after running update.

Comment: this might not be related, but phpunit should be in require-dev not require, and try with 4.1.* which is stable, as for 4.2, it is an alpha release.

Comment: Try updating your composer to the lastest build, and deleting any cache in ~/.composer ? I had some problems with an old composer version not finding certain libs correctly some time ago.

Comment: Hi Oli, i have already done those things but thanks anyway.

Comment: Hi Mamdouh, you were correct! I added the dependency to require-dev and now it worked! You can add your comment as an answer if you want to. The lesson here must be : the difference between require and require dev aren't only in the way composer handles them. Some dependencies require to be downloaded with require-dev (as they should of course anyway). As a short sidenote: i had to run "composer update --dev -vvv" thrice before it ran through the process without hanging somewhere. It seems like composer can be a bit shaky when downloading some times...

Comment: @lowkey - thanks for digging deep into it and providing a feedback, I answered the question, and as for your comment. Apparently, require and require-dev are not just labels and a way of organizing your packages dependency, it also provides a strict requirement on where the package should be included as you already mentioned.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reason the addition of PHPUnit fails is because you have TWO keys named "require" in your composer.json, which is illegal. The last instance overwrites the first instance - which overwrites the added PHPUnit requirement.

Only after changing this to "require-dev", which is a different key, Composer can detect that you want PHPUnit.

```
{
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
    "keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
    "license": "MIT",
    "require": {
        "laravel/framework": "4.1.*",
        "laravelbook/ardent": "dev-master",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "4.2.*" // i have also tried with 3.7 and 3.8
    },

    // deleted lines here...

    "minimum-stability": "stable",
        "require": {
            "laravelbook/ardent": "dev-master"
        }

}
```

See that mention of "require" as the last, badly indented key inside the JSON? This will confuse Composer at the least. I'm pretty sure "laravelbook/ardent" has a dependency on "laravel/framework" and plenty of additional stuff, so you didn't see that your first require key was overwritten.

Suggestion: Always use the command line to add stuff - it is way easier, and you don't have to take care of correct JSON formatting:

```
composer require --dev phpunit/phpunit:~4.0
```

This will add the dependency to the composer.json file and then download it right away if there are no conflicts. It will also write a new, cleanly formatted composer.json file. You'd have spotted your error quickly if Composer had the chance to remove the double key.

Comment: Thanks, actually that answer seems to be spot on! Great advice on adding everything through command line to automate as much as possible and eleminate syntax / semantic errors.

Answer (score 2):

as my comment indicated that phpunit should be in require-dev not require, and to try it with version 4.1.* which is stable, and not with 4.2, as it is an alpha release. And as lowkey mentioned in his comment:

> the difference between require and require dev aren't only in the way
>   composer handles them. Some dependencies require to be downloaded with
>   require-dev (as they should of course anyway). As a short sidenote: i
>   had to run "composer update --dev -vvv" thrice before it ran through
>   the process without hanging somewhere. It seems like composer can be a
>   bit shaky when downloading some times

so the direct answer is: phpunit should be included in require-dev not require, and it is always preferable to install a stable version rather than a beta.

Comment: In fact the conclusion why it worked is wrong. PHPUnit will run happily as "require" dependency, but the reason "require-dev" is suggested is that it should not be needed to run the software in production - and it makes for a cleaner install if you only add the dependencies needed for the software to run, not for the software to be developed, onto the production server.

Comment: @Sven - I agree with what you said, and that's why I mentioned in my comment that this might be irrelevant. However, the results was it worked with him in require-dev and it didn't by including it in require. and this is why I came up with this conclusion.